# Can't see insights on GitHub

Tags: github

I want to access pages such as community, contributors to see the effect of members on the repository, but I cannot click it because it is disabled. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These insights are only available in public repositories with *GitHub Free* and *GitHub Free for organisations* as well as in public and private repositories with *GitHub Pro*, *GitHub Team* and *GitHub Enterprise Cloud*.

More details can be found in the [overview of GitHub's products and pricing plans](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/githubs-products).